# Finding the period of $f(x) = \cos(x)-\cos(2x)$

Tags: calculus

How can I show analytically (easy way) that the function $f(x) = \cos(x)-\cos(2x)$ has a period of $2\pi$ ?

I can find the period solving $f(x)=f(x+T)$.

$\cos(x)-\cos(2x) = \cos(x+T)-\cos(2x+2T)$. If $T=2\pi$ then:

$\cos(x)-\cos(2x) = \cos(x+2\pi)-\cos(2x+4\pi)$

This last statement is true.

The demonstration can be done in this way?

thanks in advance

Comment: I make mistake. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: The period of a fourier series is the period of the longest "wavelength" involved. This follows from the orthogonality property: shorter wavelengths cannot cancel out what the longer ones did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$f(x+2\pi)=\cos (x+2\pi)-\cos (2(x+2\pi))= \ldots $

Answer (score 0):

Correct, but you have also to check there does not exits a smaller $T^\prime < T$ which would also be a period of $f$.